# Unable to upload file facing Warning: move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

In this question I want to upload file in php but I am unable to upload file and I am getting this "Warning: move_uploaded". [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSA24.jpg)
I have attached a error Screen Shot.

```
This is my **uploadhtml.php** file 

<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload your files</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <p>Upload your file</p>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"></input><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload"></input>
  </form>
</body>
</html>


This is my **upload.php** file

<?php

  if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
  {
    $path = "uploads/";
    $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path))
    {
      echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']). 
      " has been uploaded";
    }

    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add yours to the absolute local path.

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/uploads/";
```

So your final $path will be like `/var/www/html/project/upload/filename`

And `move_uploaded_file()` never creates the folders, So you should have created the upload folder yourself.

Comment: Awesome, Happy coding :)